# Should a citrus tree growing very close to the house be killed?

Tags: trees, fruit-trees

The previous owner of my house grew a citrus tree less than 1 foot away from the house. I don't know the exact species of this tree, but it produces orange-colored tangerine-sized fruits that are sour. It is about 8 feet tall now. I'm worried that the roots will continue growing and damage the foundation of my house or rupture water pipes. What do you suggest me do with this tree? Kill it? If so, how? With pesticide or with a chainsaw?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a basement that tree is definitely too close.  If your house is on a concrete slab it is probably still too close. Tree roots [rarely damage concrete foundations](http://www.mortonarb.org/tree-plant-advice/article/16888/tree-roots-and-foundation-damage.html) but you are right to worry about them growing towards water sources. The consequences of leaving it could be cracks in the concrete slab or foundation of your house.

The tree should come down and the best way is the hard way: a shovel and you....

I would not consider putting herbicides next to my house and if you have water pipes in the area hand digging is the best solution.

Comment: I have a chainsaw and will cut it down. What do I do about the stump and roots? Do citrus tree's roots continue growing even after the tree is cut? I've heard some other species continue growing...

Comment: You're right, most plants will continue to grow after cutting down. What you need is a stump killer of some kind - in the UK, that would be SBK, a brushwood killer, or Round Up stumpkiller. I prefer SBK because you drill into the stump to make holes, fill only the holes with the (liquid) SBK, cover with something and leave. So long as you don't spill it everywhere, it only affects the stump you've treated.